# embed photo album hosted on flickr.com using flickr module not showing photo album

Tags: 8, media, files

I am attempting to use the [Flickr](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickr) module  flickr-8.x-1.0-alpha2 along with [Flickr API](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickrapi) and [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox) module to display a album of recent photos from  Flickr.com.

I have setup the API keys. and added flickr setings in Text formats and editors, but the it doesnt producing any output for the photoset.

However its working for single  `[flickr-photo:id=3711935987].`
and when i tried with `[flickr-photoset:id=72157626766436507]` for photo album its not working .
 giving error in the Flickr module Notice: Undefined index: in Drupal\flickr\Service\Photos->photoGetSize();

does i miss any settings ?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely you have photos in that set that aren't available in the size you've set the photos to display in.

[Flickr module documentation > Sizes](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/flickr#sizes)

> TAKE CARE, the c (800px) size is missing on Flickr images uploaded before March 1, 2012. Check if it exists on the Flickr photo page > Actions > View all sizes.

More info and debug inspiration in the 7.x documentation: [Flickr Editor Guide 7.x-1.7](https://www.drupal.org/node/2477263)

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is quite confusing in that point, but I think single images have a default size, photosets don't. You have to define it.

```
[flickr-photoset:id=72157626766436507, size=-]
```

or

```
[flickr-photoset:id=72157626766436507, size=z]
```

for example.

I managed to get it working that way. More about sizes in Flickr here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2477263

The default image size can be selected when configuring the Text Editor Format.

Also, try to create a new user and assign content editing privileges to him/her with the "Flickr" editor text format, and add the photos with that user account.